# Como descobrir o nome de um botão pelo código fonte?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, button

Estou trabalhando com uma biblioteca [python](/questions/tagged/python) chamada [splinter](/questions/tagged/splinter), que simula um navegador web. Já li a respeito de como usa-la, e para clicar em um botão, é só dar um comando que envolve o nome do botão. Porém, diferentemente de outros sites, eu não consigo descobrir o nome dele. Quando eu vou ao código fonte, a linha que diz a respeito do botão é essa:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;" value="Criar Conta! />
```

O que eu faço?

Comment: É que esse controle aí não tem um nome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
from splinter import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.visit("url aqui")
    button = browser.find_by_value('Criar Conta!')[0] # agarramos o button pelo seu valor
    button.click()
```

Note que tem um pequeno erro no HTML que colocou, deve fechar as aspas no `value=...`:

```
...value="Criar Conta!" />
```

Answer (score 4):

É que esse controle aí não tem um nome.

Você ainda pode usar outras formas para se referir ao `input`, como css, xpath, tag, id, value, text.

Documentação para encontrar elementos: *[Splinter Docs](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/finding.html)*

Exemplo: você pode usar o valor do formulário para achá-lo, já que, provavelmente, deve ser o único botão com o valor "Criar conta !":

`browser.find_by_value('Criar conta!')`